# Why generic parameter type with constraint cannot match pattern but using constraint type directly does?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am building a typed event utils and want to provide customized event types supporting. The idea comes from [bterlson/strict-event-emitter-types](https://github.com/bterlson/strict-event-emitter-types). Within the [Demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=13&pc=2#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAyBLAzjYA7YKAQSgHMsAVZYAHgoD44BeOAbQoF05Rc8ATLGwAUAOjEBDMlgBccDHgBmhOAFUAlM0bi8iDgFgAUHDgB%20VYeOz2XHvgFsAbhAx8uZ1lyucA3IcMBjABtxLEEKYBwAUQd8GDpqPmjYgFlxMG4QXnsAbwByAFcwPnFcXNlsl1k8fIBbACNCAF9GxmyLYzh-CDwcKHz-GGghDTajDvGAegmEAAtsEWAajBghAqKS4FyAGjhsuT5ZAEY4Ro1IqChoAEI4dvHjLp74YBi8GEEWAgB3OHCo17iezWxVK5X2VVqDSgJxO9GGd3uL1iWAWSxWwI2212lTgh1OCMafjGxjA%20TqgQw-m4aPiKAyWUEAGtgIgIApfgkkm9UmA4UgULIqCgdmIRCDxLJMDh8IQSOQhbQFYkATz2NQOPQRoSDI0gA), I cannot add a generic type to extends predefined events. I dont known how to fix it. Any way to workaround?

**Update: demo**

```
export type ListenerArgsType<T> = [T] extends [(...args: infer U) => any]
  ? U
  : [T] extends [void] ? [] : [T];

class TestEvent<TypedEventMap extends {'update': {id: number}}> {
    constructor() {
        // this.emit('update', { id: 1 }) Error! 
        const events = new TestEvent<{ 'update': { id: number } }>()
        events.emit('update', {id: 1})
    }

    public emit<Type extends keyof TypedEventMap>(type: Type, ...data: ListenerArgsType<TypedEventMap[Type]>) {}
}
```

Comment: There is a difference how dependent-like types are inferred inside the function body and at the call side. I haven't really found other solution other than casting inside the function body.

There is some [work in that direction][1] that you might be interested in. You might find more insides there.


  [1]: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @rusev side. I am now casting inside the function body.